# HTML/Jquery Hiding+Showing Dependencies

Tags: jquery, html, select, drop-down-menu, dependencies

So I have a drop down list and a several check boxes. The drop down list pertains to a primary choice where the user can only select one option. The check boxes pertain to a secondary choice where the user can select as many as they like but the one that they selected from the drop down list will not appear as one of the options. Here's my code so far: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZvJQz/)

So for example, if the user selects option 1 from the drop down list, then only option2-8 should be available as checkboxes. I want to essentially hide option1 and show the rest. I don't really know what this is called so I didn't know what to search or where to look. I was looking to see if there was somesort of jquery plugin for this but how should I go about doing this? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Michael, try this :

javascript

```
$(function(){
    $('#primary').on('change', function() {
        var $sec = $('.secondary'); 
        var idx = this.selectedIndex;
        $sec.find('input').attr('disabled', false).eq(idx).attr('disabled', true);
        $sec.find('label').removeClass('disabled').eq(idx).addClass('disabled');
    }).trigger('change');
});
```

CSS :

```
.disabled {
    color: gray;
}
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ZvJQz/3/)**

I have departed from the brief slightly by disabling rather than hiding the unwanted checkbox. This is maybe less confusing for the user. If not, then it's quite easy to modify the code to hide/show :

```
$('#primary').on('change', function() {
    $('.secondary').find('label').show().eq(this.selectedIndex).hide();
}).trigger('change');
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ZvJQz/4/)**

Answer (score 1):

[Check this DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/ZvJQz/8/)

You do not need a plugin for it.. Simple jQuery should be sufficient

Try this

```
$('#primary').on('change', function() {
    // Show all the options initially
    $('.secondary label').show();
    // Get the currently selected option
    var selected = $(this).val();
    // Hide the label that encases the option
    $('.secondary').find('input[type="checkbox"][value="'+ selected + '"]').closest('label').hide();

}).change();​
```

**UPDATED CODE**

For this you need to create a template of the checkboxe which can be used to populate the design when the selection changes..

```
$('#primary').on('change', function() {
    // Clone the checkbox template
    var $template = $('.template').clone();
    var selected = $(this).val();
    // Remove the selected option from cloned object
    $template.find('input[type="checkbox"][value="'+ selected + '"]').closest('label').remove(); 

    // Append to the DropDown
    $('.secondary').html( $template.html() );

}).change();​
```

[UPDATED FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/ZvJQz/2/)

Comment: Is there a way to collect all the selection boxes rather than have a gap for the hidden element?

Comment: Check the post above.. Updated it

Comment: for some reason this isn't working in my page, it still has a gap where the deleted element was. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you using the updated code..?? IF so that should not happen as we are first removing the label and then adding the html.. Can you show a working example so that can be fixed

Comment: That was because of the </br> tags.. Just remove those and add  label
{
    display: block;
}​ class.. It should be fine